# Cannot assign to 'X' in 'Y' in Swift

Tags: struct, swift

I have a dictionary with `Structs` in it. I am trying to assign the values of the `struct` when I loop through the `dictionary`. Swift is telling me `cannot assign to 'isRunning' in 'blockStatus'`. I haven't been able to find anything in the docs on this particular immutability of `dictionaries` or `structs`. 
**Straight from the playground:**

```
import Cocoa

struct BlockStatus{
 var isRunning = false
 var timeGapForNextRun = UInt32(0)
 var currentInterval = UInt32(0) 
}

var statuses = ["block1":BlockStatus(),"block2":BlockStatus()]

for (block, blockStatus) in statuses{
 blockStatus.isRunning = true
}

cannot assign to 'isRunning' in 'blockStatus'
blockStatus.isRunning = true
```

This does work if I change the `struct` to a `class`.

**I am guessing it has something to do with the fact that structs are copied and classes are always referenced?**

**EDIT:** So even if it is copying it.. Why can't I change it? It would net me the wrong result but you can change members of constants just not the constant themselves. For example you can do this:

```
class A {
    var b = 5
}

let a = A()
a.b = 6
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your guess is true.

By accessing `blockStatus`, you are creating a copy of it, in this case, it's a constant copy (iterators are always constant).

This is similar to the following:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for i in numbers {
   i = 10  //cannot assign here
}
```

References:

[Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-XID_153)

> In the example above, index is a **constant** whose value is automatically set at the start of each iteration of the loop.

[Classes and Structures](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_94)

> A value type is a type that is copied when it is assigned to a variable or constant, or when it is passed to a function. [...] All structures and enumerations are value types in Swift

[Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_300)

> Structures and enumerations are value types. By default, the properties of a value type cannot be modified from within its instance methods.
>
> However, if you need to modify the properties of your structure or enumeration within a particular method, you can opt in to mutating behavior for that method. The method can then mutate (that is, change) its properties from within the method, and any changes that it makes are written back to the original structure when the method ends. The method can also assign a completely new instance to its implicit self property, and this new instance will replace the existing one when the method ends.
>
> You can opt in to this behavior by placing the mutating keyword before the func keyword for that method:

Comment: But even if it is a copy I should be able to change the copy no? It would not give me the right result but... It is a constant but you can change members of constants. See my edit.

Comment: @Johnston Not on a constant struct.

Comment: Aha. You are correct. Do you know where it says that?

Comment: @Johnston Added a couple of references.

Comment: Good answer. I was going crazy about this. I did some further reading and, @Johnston, I have found where it says that the properties of constant structures cannot be changed. [Stored Properties of Constant Structure Instances](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_382)

Comment: I was running into this problem because I had a protocol `Foo`. If you have an array of `Foo` and you iterate through the array, you cannot set the properties of the array members because Foo might be a struct. By making `Foo` a `class` protocol I made Swift happy again.

Answer (score 6):

You could loop through the array with an index

```
for index in 0..<statuses.count {
    // Use your array - statuses[index]
}
```

that should work without getting "cannot assign"

Comment: I can't edit this reply, as it should contain at least 6 characters :], so I will correct you here. 1) Correct operator is "..." not ".."; 2) count should be -1 otherwise you will crash the app

Comment: @pasevin Edited it for you.

Comment: @pasevin Better still, use the half-open range operator.

Comment: agree this is clever ;]

Answer (score 4):

If 'Y' in this case is a protocol, subclass your protocol to `class`. I had a protocol:

```
 protocol PlayerMediatorElementProtocol {
      var playerMediator:PlayerMediator { get }
 }
```

and tried to set `playerMediator` from within my player mediator:

```
element.playerMediator = self
```

Which turned into the error `cannot asign 'playerMediator' in 'element'`

Changing my protocol to inherit from class fixed this issue:

```
 protocol PlayerMediatorElementProtocol : class {
      var playerMediator:PlayerMediator { get }
 }
```

**Why should it inherit from class?**

The reason it should inherit from `class` is because the compiler doesn't know what *kind* your protocol is inherited by. Structs could also inherit this protocol and you *can't assign to a property of a constant struct*.

Comment: Had the same issue except the property in my protocol was defined with `{get set}`. Adding `class` fixed it, but it seems like you should be able to set without it. Anyone know why class is needed?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the reason it should inherit from `class`. It's because the possibility of inheritance by structs